# How to expose my WP API only to this specific VUE app?

Tags: wordpress, api, vue.js, authentication

I am building an app for my own WP website and I want to lists posts by category, date... etc. I am using axios to make API calls and everything works fine.

The only problem is that I want to restrict WP API access so that only my vue.js app has access to it (app will be converted into the Android app). I was thinking to do that by using bearer token (encrypt in vue and then decrypt in WP) but I don't know **where to store that token** so the user can't find and re-use it somewhere else.

This is my current code:

```
 getPosts() {
 /* "posts" and "postsData" are defined inside data()*/
  this.$http
    .get("example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed", { params: this.postsData })
    .then((response) => {
      this.posts = response.data; 
     
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

On Google and found only solution with Vuex, but (this is important): I do not want to store users login sessions but only the simple token that will always be the same and only I will know about it.
Maybe my logic is wrong so I would like to hear other solutions **how to expose my API only to this specific VUE app**.

Thanks!

Comment: If you ever call the API from the client passing the token, they could just inspect the header

Comment: Maybe expiring tokens?

Comment: Expiry probably wouldn't help much here  (still a good idea for other reasons).  But think of this: an authenticated user doesn't need to reuse their token in the first place.  They could log in from a 3rd party app which sends headers that match the ones sent by your app, and get a fresh token that way.  You could make things difficult for non-technical users.  But it would not be a guarantee of protection against someone who was determined and knew a bit.

Comment: So, there is no solution to my problem? I have to expose my API if I want to use it in Vue apps?

Comment: You have to expose it if you want to use it on the internet.  This is the nature of http, not Vue, because http operates completely on headers which can be be sent by anyone.  If you're familiar with online games, there's a similar issue where developers try to prevent custom game clients and it's a problem for them too.  This is more of a question for security.stackexchange.  You can also see [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-web-application-to-authorized-devices-only)